# What is difference between dynamic pointer allocation for a single variable and array?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

What is the  difference between these three lines in C++?

```
int *p= new int;
int *p= new int[10];
int *p = new int[];
```

We are already dynamically declaring the memory to pointer variable p, why is it required to specifically mention pointer array size?

Comment: and the last one is an error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
 int *p = new int[];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int *p = new int;
```

This allocates enough memory for a single object of type `int` and stores a pointer to it in the pointer-to-`int` variable `p`.  This means that `*p` refers to a valid `int` object.

```
int *p = new int[10];
```

This allocates enough contiguous memory for ten objects of type `int` and stores a pointer to the first `int` in the pointer-to-`int` variable `p`.  This means that `p[0]` through `p[9]` refer to valid `int` objects.

```
int *p = new int[];
```

This statement is syntactically incorrect.  It is not valid C++, and therefore has no meaning.

> ... why is it required to specifically mention pointer array size?

How else is the memory allocator supposed to know how much memory to allocate if you don't tell it how many `int`s you need room for?

Comment: Also, it should be noted that `new` for a single object must be matched with `delete` for a single object, and `new[]` for an array must be matched with `delete[]` for an array. `new[]` stores the array count in such a way that `delete[]` knows how many objects to destruct (if needed) before freeing the underlying memory block.